# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'org'

Tags: apache, import, pyspark

I have installed pyspark in ubuntu 18.04. Now I am trying to run some    program in Jupyter Notebook where I am able to import Spark Sessions    and Context but I have to run commands like.

- import org.apache.spark.ml.feature._
- import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg._
- import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

and I am getting error **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'org'** . Please help..

Comment: You are trying to  run scala code with pyspark?

Answer (score 2):

You are running scala code in python.
To import machine learning libraries in pyspark use..

```
import pyspark.ml.*
```

Or just replace org.apache.spark to pyspark

Hope it helps